# Android StudioのアプリDL時にファイルを作りたい

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

初めまして。comsysと申します。
Android Studioについて質問があります。

現状、binファイルまでのパスまでを指定すれば印刷を行える
プログラムを書いています。
下記プログラムは正常に動作します。

```
var Filepath = File(File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "customPaper"),"print.bin").absolutePath
settings.customPaper =  Filepath
```

この場合、予めAndroid実機の外部ストレージ内に「customPaper」フォルダ、
「print.bin」ファイルを作っておかないと動作しません。

このbinファイルの作成をアプリ立ち上げ時に自動で行いたいです。

具体的にはプロジェクトの構成フォルダ内のどこかにbinファイルを仕込んで置き、
立ち上げ時にbinファイルを実機内の所定フォルダにコピーする動作を入れたいと考えています。

このような動作の実現するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どこに置いて、プログラムからどう読み込むのか、が問題なのだと思います。

ファイルは `app/src/main/assets/` 内に置いてください。

以下のようなコードで、そのファイルを開いて `InputStream` を得ることができます。

```
val resources = getResources()
val inputStream = resources.getAssets().open("test.txt")
```

あとは `inputStream.read()` で読み込んでください。

Comment: >>masm様　　ありがとうございます。InputStreamから所定のフォルダにbinファイルを作成し、無事動かすことができました。参考のために知りたいのですが、assetsフォルダの中身のbinファイルへのパスを得ることは可能でしょうか?

Comment: @comsys 方法を探してみましたが見つかりませんでした。できないのかもしれませんね。

Comment: >>masm様　調査ありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。では、今後は参照用ファイルを所定のフォルダに作る形式で活用します。